# QSqlRecord not inserting 0 into database

Tags: qt

I've come across a strange problem with QSqlRecord, its inserting null instead of '0'.
Here is example code illustrating the problem:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtSql>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

// Filename for sqlite database
QString filename = "./test.db";

// Make sure the database doesn't already exisit
if (QFile::exists(filename)){
    QFile::remove(filename);
}

// Connect to the database
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName(filename);

db.open();

// Create test table
QSqlQuery query(db);

bool result;
result = query.exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'test' ('key' TEXT, 'value' INTEGER)");
db.commit();
// Insert the test value into the database
QSqlTableModel model(0, db);

// Set the table
model.setTable("test");

// Set up the data
QSqlRecord record = model.record();
record.setValue("key", "first");
record.setValue("value", 1);
result = model.insertRecord(-1, record);
model.submitAll();

record.setValue("key", "second");
record.setValue("value", 0);
result = model.insertRecord(-1, record);
model.submitAll();

record.setValue("key", "third");
record.setValue("value", 2);
result = model.insertRecord(-1, record);
model.submitAll();
// Commit changes and close database]
db.commit();
db.close();
}
```

If I query `test.db` I get:

```
sqlite> select * from test;
first|1
second|
third|2
```

Note there is no value for the second entry.

I'm using Qt 5.0.1, with Mingw 4.7 on Windows 7.

Comment: Does `submitAll()` return true? What does `QSqlQueryModel::lastError ()` says?

Comment: submitAll() returns true, and model.lastError() returns no error ( QSqlError(-1, “”, “”) )